# One to many MongoDB vs SQL

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I'm used to working in MongoDB, and if I'm creating a 0-n or 1-n relationship there I can just create an array containing all the IDs for the documents I'm referencing, like this:

```
var Company = new Schema({
  name: String,
  Employee_IDs: [String]
});
```

And now I'm trying to figure out how to do this in SQL, am I right by claiming that the equivalent to this MongoDB relationship in SQL looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Company(
Company_ID INT NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Company_ID)
)

CREATE TABLE Employee(
Employee_ID INT NOT NULL,
Company_ID INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Employee_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Company_ID) REFERENCES Company(Company_ID)
)
```

Is this correct?

Comment: It looks good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is typical approach in relational databases.

Of course, employee can work for only one company in this model. In real world there can be case when somebody works for two or more companies. Then you would need referential table and create m:n relation like this:

```
CREATE TABLE CompanyEmployee
(
    Company_ID INT NOT NULL,
    Employee_ID INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Company_ID, Employee_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Company_ID) REFERENCES Company(Company_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID) REFERENCES Employee(Employee_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    Employee_ID INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Employee_ID)
);
```